# How to know if my guitar's neck is bent or not?

Tags: guitar, maintenance

When I go to my guitar tech, he said that my guitar's neck is already bent. **How to know it** or **what are the methods to see if it's already bent or not?**

Well, my guitar don't really have a *truss-rod*. So, it can't be repaired.

Comment: What reasons does the tech have for saying this? What make and model of guitar is it?

Comment: @Tim my really old Yamaha CG122MS :p made in china.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clamp down the first and the last fret with either capos or elastic bands and measure the distance between the string and the 7th fret ideally done with a feeler gauge but a ruler is acceptable. Usually the measurement will be around .007 inches (a slight up-bow) or there will no gap (a straight neck).

However, it should be noted that if you have a significant back-bow there will also be no gap at the 7th fret. However in such a case, if you are unable see it via a glance you can use a straight edge and lay it flat on the 7th fret and you should be able to see an increasing downward angle. Very similar to the idea of running a string across your yard to see if the ground is level.

As for the other extreme ie an up-bow there should be a fairly large gap at the 7th fret.

Comment: +1 - been fixing guitars for years and this is the best means to check if a neck is truly bent.